# map() method mutating the calling Array

Tags: javascript

map() can't mutate the calling array, instead it returns a new Array with modified values.
But, the following code mutating the original Array, is there any wrong in my understanding?

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arr.map((num, index, arr1) => {
  return arr1[index] = num * 2;
});
console.log(arr); // [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Comment: The `.map()` callback _can_ mutate the array, which is what you're doing with `arr1[index] =`. Instead, return the new values `return num * 2;` without assigning them to the original array. The `.map()` method will then return the new array: `const newArr = arr.map(...)`

Comment: "The .map() callback can mutate the array", I don't know this thing. Everybody saying map() doesn't mutate the original Array, but when I run the above code, it mutated the original Array. Thanks, I will do some more experiments on it.

Comment: @rajesh _“`map` **doesn’t** mutate the array”_ is correct; it doesn’t mutate arrays _by default, on its own_. _“`map` **can’t** mutate the array”_ is _not_ correct.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you're mutating the original array by passing its reference into the callback function inside `map()` (`arr1`) and then manually accessing the indices. It will create a new array if you just return the value from that function.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const arr1 = arr.map((num) => {
    return num * 2;
});
console.log(arr); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(arr1); // [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Comment: I know this, but as per Mozilla docs, map() doesn't change original Array, but now I am assuming that if the array is passed as third argument in the function, then Array will be mutated.

Comment: Yep. Third argument is the actual array you called `map()` on. It's optional, but if a value is passed, that will get mutated.

Answer (score 1):

> The third argument to the callback function of [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is the
> original/source array on which the map is called upon

The `arr` and `arr1` are both same i.e both are referencing on the same array, You can see it by using `console.log(arr === arr1)`. So what ever you operation perform on the `arr1`, it gonna affect the `arr`.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arr.map((num, index, arr1) => {
  console.log(arr1 === arr);
  return num * 2;
});
```

You can just return `num * 2` from the callback function. `map` internally creates a new array and return it. So you don't have to assign it as

```
arr1[index] = num * 2
```

You can also make it `one-liner` as:

```
arr.map((num, index, arr1) => num * 2)
```

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const result = arr.map((num, index, arr1) => {
  return num * 2;
});
console.log(arr); // [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
console.log(result); // [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Comment: pls check your code, arr is not mutated

Comment: Yeah, If you want to mutate the array then you should use `forEach` in the first place, no need to use `map` here. `map` is used to return a new array and if you are returning new array then no need to mutate the original array.

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) **creates a new array** populated with the results of **calling a provided function** on every element in the calling array.

Here its specifed that you must call or execute a function on every element of calling array.

**What is the issue with your code?**

You are not actually calling a function, you are instead updating the original array. If you are looking to create a new array by multiplying each node of the element with 2, you should do something like below.

**Working Example**

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const newArray = arr.map((nodeFromOriginalArray, indexOfCurrentElement, arrayFromMapCalled) => {
  return nodeFromOriginalArray * 2;
});
console.log(arr);
console.log(newArray);
```

**Lets debug the paremeters inside the map function.**

Here we have provided three arguments.

First argument `nodeFromOriginalArray`: The current element being processed in the array. This will be each node from your calling array.

Second argument `indexOfCurrentElement`: The index of the current element being processed in the array. Which means, the index of current element in calling array.

**Third argument** `arrayFromMapCalled`: The array `map` was called upon. This is the array on which the `map` function is getting executed. Please note, this is the original array. Updating properties inside this array results in updating your calling array. This is what happened in your case.

You should not modify your original array, which is the third parameter. Instead, you should return your node multipled by 2 inside `map` and assign this to a new array. Updating the third paramater inside the `map` function will mutate your calling array.

Answer (score 0):

When calling map on an array, you provide a `mapper` with three arguments, an item in the array, it's index and the array itself (as you've represented in your snippet).

`map` takes the value returned by the function `mapper` as the element at the  index in a new array returned by the operation.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
const doubled = arr.map(x => x * 2) // [2,4,6,8, 10]
```

A over simplified implementation of map (without the index and originalArray params) might look like this. Let's assume that instead of being a method on the array instance, it's a function that takes an array and a mapper function.

> I would not recommend re-implementing in production code, there's the native implementation as well as several libraries such as lodash and underscore that implement it.

```js
function map(arr, mapper) {
  const result = [];
  for (const item of arr) {
    const resultItem = mapper(item);
    result.push(resultItem);
  }
  return result;
}

function double(x) {
  return x * 2;
}


const doubled = map([1,2,3,4,5,6], double); // [2, 4, 6, 8 ,10, 12]
```